# How to avoid duplicate field in database while inserting the product

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have question to avoid Duplicate field in Database while using JSP and Servlet. Because when i am inserting product it can duplicate. So if anyone can add the duplicate value it shows Item/product already available. So i need to know how is that possible to perform the task.

Comment: set the UNIQUE constraint in the database

Comment: Or insert using a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score -2):

Use unique key constraint,If you can't make the primary key, the only way to prevent inserting it again, is doing a select first.
https://www.daniweb.com/programming/databases/threads/279923/check-for-duplicates-before-insert

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.